# qooxdoo mobile - click handlers not firing in ios

Tags: ios, mobile, qooxdoo

I have a mobile app built using phonegap +qx mobile 3.5.

I have a page implemented using qooxdoo mobile which has a header implemented using qooxdoo controls. The content section of the page is loading from an external system using a ajax call which returns a string(html+css). The html has built in click handlers which are not firing on  ios. The html works fine when loaded directly without qx.

This is an existing app in android and seems to work fine there. Can someone help me get this working on ios?

**EDIT :** I am using native scroll and not the custom scroll plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is caused by the used scrolling method.

If you just remove the macro "qx.mobile.nativescroll" out of your config.json,
qx.Mobile detects itself whether to use NativeScroll or iScroll.

In version 3.5 that means, Windows Phone 8 and iOS7 are using the native scrolling.

Do not forget to rebuild after removal.